# Color Edge Detection in an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, edge-detection

As shown in this image, I want to label the edges of three branches with purple color and filter other area as purely white color (or other background color). I use Laplacian and sober to do image gradient and then use canny method to do edge detection. However, it does not reach my expectation.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Read image
    im = cv2.imread("crop.jpg")

    # Calculation of Laplacian 
    laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(imCrop,cv2.CV_64F) 

    edges = cv2.Canny(laplacian,35,35)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to improve it to get your goal:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
#convert to hsv
i = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
i[: ,:, 0]=0
i[: ,:, 2]=0
#s channel 
cv2.imshow("s channel", i)
```

[image: Image output with s channel]

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution as below,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Read image
    im = cv2.imread("crop.jpg")
    a=np.copy(im)

    a[:,:,0]=255
    a[:,:,1]=255
    a[a>150]=255

    plt.imshow(a)
```